# How to save multiple checkboxes as integer in DB

Tags: php, laravel

I have this in my view:

[image]

And I have only one field in my DB and that is `driverslicensetype`

How to save this to the DB so that whatever types user chooses will save the picked ones like this:

```
        /* ABCD
         *
         * A: 0 No 1 AM 2 A1 3 A2 4 A;
         * B: 0 No 1 B1 2 B 3 BE
         * C: 0 No 1 C1 2 C1E 3 C 4 CE
         * D: 0 No 1 D1 2 D1E 3 D 4 DE
         */
```

So if user chooses A and B only the saved number should be 3300

A B and C would be 3230

A B C D would be 3233

B C1 would be 0210

and so on.

So I have made this in my view:

```
<div class="col">
    <?php
    $driverslicense_types = [
        'AM',
        'A1',
        'A2',
        'A',
        'B1',
        'B',
        'BE',
        'C1',
        'C1E',
        'C',
        'CE',
        'D1',
        'D1E',
        'D',
        'DE'
    ]
    ?>
    @foreach($driverslicense_types as $type)
        <div class="col-md-3">
            {!! Form::checkbox('driverslicense_type'.$type,'1', false, ['id'=>'driverslicense_type'.$type, 'class' => 'checkbox-style']) !!}
            {!! Form::label('driverslicense_type'.$type, $type, ['id'=>'driverslicense_type'.$type, 'class'=>'checkbox-style-3-label']) !!}
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

So, how can I save this in my controller?

Comment: Are you only able to choose one per row?

Comment: No...you can choose whatever you want

Comment: I would suggest you to learn about binary operations and use them to save your data.
You chould then use 15 bits to represent the selected values:
`0001` for the first row as example could be A, while `1010` would be `AM` and `A2`.

Comment: You might want to find a way to normalize the database, otherwise the numbers may not match up right (A1+A2 = A+AM). Create a table for the license types, with columns user_id and license_type.

Comment: i am not allowed to change anything but i would if i could believe me!

Comment: if a user chooses the top number of the class it is to presume that he has all of the under classes

Comment: You could use bitwise operators to manipulate the checkboxes and comprise them into a single field in your DB, but I would advise that you don't as it would basically be a form of serialising multiple bits of data and storing them in a single field, which violates 1NF.  It would be better to either have one field per checkbox, or have a dependant table that stores one row per selected checkbox.

Comment: are you going to search the mysql for these driver licenses? if not, you can just serialize them.

Comment: So what would happen if you chose A, AM, B1, BE, C, C1? Wouldn't that end up being 6 numbers instead of 4?

Comment: if you pick greater number in the class that number is the only one for that type. one class one number....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to remember is that checkboxes that are not checked on the form are NOT posted to the script.

Second, if you put the required value in the `value=""` attribute rather than the default of `1` that you are using you will get some useful data back from the form

Start with your array of types and give each type code the correct value.

```
/* ABCD
 *
 * A: 0 No 1 AM 2 A1 3 A2 4 A;
 * B: 0 No 1 B1 2 B 3 BE
 * C: 0 No 1 C1 2 C1E 3 C 4 CE
 * D: 0 No 1 D1 2 D1E 3 D 4 DE
 */

$dl_types = [
    'aaas' => ['AM'=>1, 'A1'=>2, 'A2'=>3, 'A'=>4],
    'bees' => ['B1'=>1, 'B'=>2, 'BE'=>3],
    'cees' => ['C1'=>1, 'C1E'=>2, 'C'=>3, 'CE'=>4],
    'dees' => ['D1'=>1, 'D1E'=>2, 'D'=>,3 'DE'=>4]
]
```

Now use this to load a value into the `value=""` attribute on the form for each of the checkboxes.

My Laravel is very rusty, so please check this and dont beat me up if I made a syntax error here

```
@foreach($dl_types as $name => $subarray)
    @foreach ($subarray as $type => $value)
        <div class="col-md-3">
        {!! Form::checkbox($name.'[]',$value, false, ['id'=>'driverslicense_type'.$type, 'class' => 'checkbox-style']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('driverslicense_type'.$type, $type, ['id'=>'driverslicense_type'.$type, 'class'=>'checkbox-style-3-label']) !!}
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Now when the form is posted you should get 4 arrays like this in `$_POST`

```
$_POST['aaas'][....]
$_POST['bees'][....]
$_POST['cees'][....]
$_POST['dees'][....]
```

The sub arrays of each of these will contain the values of the checked checkboxes you placed in the `value=""` attribute for each one.

So as you say under another answer, you only need the largest from each category to get the answer you want regardless of how many `aaas` for example were checked, you can then do this for each category

```
$result_string = '';        // init the string

if ( !isset($_POST['aaas'] ) {
    // nothing in the A set was checked
    $result_string .= '0';
} else {
    $result_string .= $_POST['aaas'][count($_POST['aaas']-1);
}

if ( !isset($_POST['bees'] ) {
    $result_string .= '0';
} else {
    $result_string .= $_POST['bees'][count($_POST['bees']-1);
}

if ( !isset($_POST['cees'] ) {
    $result_string .= '0';
} else {
    $result_string .= $_POST['cees'][count($_POST['cees']-1);
}

if ( !isset($_POST['dees'] ) {
    $result_string .= '0';
} else {
    $result_string .= $_POST['dees'][count($_POST['dees']-1);
}
```

You should end up with a result string containing 4 numeric characters that you can store onto your database.

Comment: Not bad not bad...i need some time to test this but you have a vote up from me!

Comment: I expected you might need to do some testing. Just comment on here if anything is way off or you need something else figuring out

Comment: there were some small mistakes, but i fixed it....and still working on it... i like it how you think!

Comment: I spotted the `endforeach` but feel free to edit the answer to fix any others, or let me know. I would not want to be posting bad code

Comment: I finished it 2 hours ago. It works but I made some changes. I will post it so everyone can learn somethong